# QVector and QMap. Program crash, is this invalid code?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore, qmap, qvector

I am trying to put values from a QMap into a QVector, but program crash and I get no good debug information. I am not used to C++ container classes and assume I have done something illegal. The code is shown below:

```
MyClass::MyClass()
{
    myQMap = new QMap<QString, QString>();
}

void someFunc(QString data1, QString data2)
{
    QVector<double> a(30);
    QVector<double> x(30);

    myQMap->insert(data1, data2);

    QMap<QString, QString>::const_iterator i = myQMap->constBegin();
    while(i != myQMap->constEnd())
    {
        a.append(i.key().toDouble());
        x.append(i.value().toDouble());
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not incrementing your iterator in your `while` loop.

Comment: @RA.: I guess the two beers I drank did not help my programming... It works now. Thank you! ;)

Comment: By the way, you don't need to allocate Qt containers on the heap -- just write `QMap<> myQMap`, not `QMap<> *myQMap`. All Qt containers store their internal data on the heap already.

Comment: I see, that is good to know :) Only difference is readability or is there any downside to do as I have done?

Comment: The big downside when you explicitly allocate things by having a pointer variable and using `new` (vs. having a non-pointer variable) is that you have to spend lines of code `delete`ing those allocations (and remember to actually delete them all). If you use a non-pointer variable, the item will be cleaned up automatically when the containing item is cleaned up - you don't need to worry about remembering to call `delete` and you don't have to clutter up your code with `delete` calls.

Comment: `QMap<> myQMap` would not even compile. That is invalid syntax. It is better to use valid syntax when explaning something to a newcomer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your loop will be "endless" in the sense that you are not advancing the iterator instance. That means, you will shortly append 30 items and the `a` and `x` vector container will be saturated, and then you will append further on... you cannot do this without any issues.

The simple fix is to increment the iterator by using something like the following snippet:

```
QMap<QString, QString>::const_iterator i;
for (i = myQMap->constBegin(); i != myQMap->constEnd(); ++i)
{
    a.append(i.key().toDouble());
    x.append(i.value().toDouble());
}
```

That being said, I am not sure why you are doing this iterator logic manually when you could just use foreach as follows:

```
foreach (const QPair<QString, QString> &myPair, myQMap)
{
    a.append(myPair.first.toDouble());
    x.append(myPair.second.toDouble());
}
```

Disclaimer: I have not tried to compile this code, but it should demonstrate the concept.